# Execute SSIS package and set package parameters in catalog

Tags: sql-server, ssis, jobs, ssis-2012

I have created a stored procedure to execute an ssis package in the catalog and set the package parameters dynamically at run time. I then create a job step to use the Operating system (CMDEXEC) Command to run the dtexec utility. The code is below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Administration].[prc_Exec_LoadbenefitStatement_SSIS_TEST1]
    @Destination varchar(250), 
    @FinancialFile varchar(250), 
    @StaticFile varchar(250), 
    @StatementType varchar(15),
    @ExternalID varchar(20),
    @SourceSystemID varchar(20)
AS
DECLARE @jid as uniqueidentifier
BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @statement varchar(2000)

    BEGIN 
        SET @statement = 'dtexec /ISServer "\SSISBD\AFFS\KhanyaStatements\Khanya_LoadBenefitStatement.dtsx" /SERVER "XXXXX\SQL01"'

        SET @statement = @Statement + ' /Par "Destination";' + @Destination
        SET @statement = @Statement + ' /Par "FinancialFile";' + @FinancialFile
        SET @statement = @Statement + ' /Par "StaticFile";' + @StaticFile
        SET @statement = @Statement + ' /Par "StatementType";' + @StatementType
        SET @statement = @Statement + ' /Par "ExternalID";' + @ExternalID
        SET @statement = @Statement + ' /Par "SourceSystemID";' + @SourceSystemID
    END

    DECLARE @jname varchar(128)
    SET @jname = cast(newid() as char(36))

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
        @job_name           = @jname,
        @enabled            = 1,
        @category_name      = 'KhanyaStatements_SSIS',
        @delete_level       = 3,
        @job_id             = @jid OUTPUT

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver
        @job_id             = @jid,
        @server_name        = 'XXXXX\SQL01'

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
        @job_id             = @jid,
        @step_name          = 'Execute SSIS',
        @subsystem          = 'CMDEXEC',
        @proxy_name         = 'pr_KhanyaStatements',
        @command            = @statement

    DECLARE @returncode tinyint 
    EXEC @returncode = msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 
        @job_id             = @jid

    SELECT @returncode

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I have created the Credential, Proxy and Job Category. When I execute the proc the return code is 0 for success but I can clearly see that the package did not execute. Please assist?

Comment: Show us a print of your statements

Comment: Your /Par statements are in the wrong format you need something like: /Par "\"$Project::Destination\"" + ";" + @Destination. It might help if you create a job manually through SSMS with some static parameters then query [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] to find the correct format.

Comment: dtexec /ISServer "\SSISBD\AFFS\KhanyaStatements\Khanya_LoadBenefitStatement.dtsx" /SERVER "XXXXX\SQL01" /Par "Destination";\\XXXXX\Khanya_statements_live\ /Par "FinancialFile";KHC_BISFinancial2787.csv /Par "StaticFile";KHC_BISStatic2787.csv /Par "StatementType";Benefit /Par "ExternalID";2787 /Par "SourceSystemID";7

Comment: Thanks Steve! I'm on my way to using the correct format